# How to make screen scrollable without XML file?

Tags: java, android, xml, scrollable

I made a 2D Andorid ConnectFour game with Android Studio. The user can set the board size at the beginning of the game and I didn't want to limit the screen size.However if user set size bigger than 7*7 ,the game board does not fit on the screen ,so I want to make scrollable, when user set size bigger than 7*7.

My question is I didn't use XML layout file. I use only Java file.When I searched "How to make screen scrollable?",all answers contained XML layout file solutions.But I don't have XML file, at the same time my game works good when size is smaller than 7*7. So is there a way to make screen scrollable with Java code.

I use like this

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MyView a = new MyView(this);
        setContentView(a);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrollable); //if I use this code line to make scrollable , my game board gone and create a blank scrollable screen.
```

Comment: Any XML widget can be made manually... Make a  ScrollView ,and add views to it

Comment: @cricket_007 Could you see my edited post?
If I use last code line `MyView a` is gone and come a blank scrollable screen. But I don't want it. How can I combine both setContentView method?

Comment: You can't. But you could build `MyView` onto the XML, then use a layout file with setContentView

Comment: @cricket_007 could you give me an example for build `MyView` onto XML?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this,may be it will help

```js
ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
  LinearScrollView linearScrollView = new LinearScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

    linearScrollView.addView(linearLayout);

    scrollView.addView(linearScrollView);

    setContentView(scrollView);
```